# Bullets on a list overlapping in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have some trouble getting a HTML list in chrome working. In Firefox every thing works fine.

I made a Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1vxsq5bw/2/

And this is the markup:

```
<ul>
    <li class="field-label-inline">
      <div class="label-inline field-label">Lorem:</div>
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">2</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="field-label-inline">
      <div class="label-inline field-label">Ipsum:</div>
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">3</div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>`
```

And the style:

```
.field-label-inline .field-label, .field-label-inline .field-items {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: floating left is causing them to overlap

Comment: if you remove the `float:left;` styling it seems to work fine in chrome

Comment: You may change `float:left;` to `display:inline-block;` so it would behave like list element.

Comment: display:inline-block; worked. Thanks!